Turning rpact object into a nice looking table in Rstudio Viewer
I'm trying to replicate the nice looking table in Rstudio Viewer of an example on the rpact vignette, where the output summary table is in tabular format. But my output summary table just show up in the Console and not in the Viewer. I have tried kbl and gtsummary but not successful.
getDesignGroupSequential(
    beta = 0.05,
    typeOfDesign = "asKD",
    gammaA = 1,
    typeBetaSpending = "bsOF"
) |>
    summary()

My output

I want to replicate this output instead.


Have you tried data.table()?

I just tried data.table(as.data.frame(summary(samplesize))), and did not work either unfortunately...

Try this if it is the solution you are looking for: mtcars_sum <- summary(mtcars)
reactable::reactable(mtcars_sum, striped = T, highlight = T, bordered = T, compact=  T)

That didn't do the trick either. Thanks for your help!
